# jQuery UI Autocomplete in MVC modal window

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to implement the autocomplete jQuery UI function in a Bootstrap modal window, but it does not work.

[screenshot module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Iin.png) 
[console debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E59wM.png)

Take the steps of not returning a partial view, also already implement jQuery CSS styles, the truth works for me in full views, but why when calling a modal window does not? any help for me?

My Script of where I call the Modal window:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").on("click", "a.dialog-window", null, function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $link = $(this);
            var title = $link.text();
            $('#AgregarProducto.modal-title').html(title);
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
                $('#AgregarProducto').modal('show');
            }
            else {
                $.get(url, function (data) {
                    $('#AgregarProducto .te').html(data);
                    $('#AgregarProducto').modal();
                }).success(function () { $('input:text:visible:first').focus(); });    
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My Modal Windows:

```
   <div class="form-group">         
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" name="producto" id="producto" />              
        </div>
    </div>

    @section Scripts {    

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")    
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>

    <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#producto").autocomplete({
                    source: "/Salidas/BuscarProducto"
                });
            });
    </script>    
    }
```

My Controller:

```
   public JsonResult BuscarProducto(string term)
    {
        using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
        {
            var resultado = db.Productos.Where(x => x.v_Nombre.Contains(term)).Select(y => y.v_Nombre).Take(5).ToList();

            return Json(resultado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you try running `$("#producto").autocomplete` after the modal is shown? jQuery might not be able to do the right DOM manipulation until the modal is completely shown. You'll need to handle the `shown.bs.modal` event.

Comment: Would you suggest that I make the change in the script that calls the modal? or make the change in the script within the modal?
@kettch

Comment: I would do it from the $(document).ready function at the top, just before you call `show` is fine.

Comment: I modified my code in this way ... after showing the modal, activate the autocomplete function ....

  if (url.indexOf ('#') == 0) {
             $ ('# AddProduct'). Modal ('show');
             $ ("# product"). modal ('show.bs.modal');
         }  @kettch but not working :(

Comment: I've added an answer that hopefully clarifies things. @Fytito Ambiado

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an event handler for `shown.bs.modal` before you show the modal itself.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").on("click", "a.dialog-window", null, function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $link = $(this);
            var title = $link.text();
            $('#AgregarProducto.modal-title').html(title);
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
                $('#AgregarProducto').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                    $("#producto").autocomplete({
                         source: "/Salidas/BuscarProducto"
                    });
                }
                $('#AgregarProducto').modal('show');
            }
            else {
                $.get(url, function (data) {
                    $('#AgregarProducto .te').html(data);
                    $('#AgregarProducto').modal();
                }).success(function () { $('input:text:visible:first').focus(); });    
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working? What is the intended behavior, and what is the actual behavior? Also, do you know if the `shown.bs.modal` event code is running? Please add your updated code to the end of your question so that we can look at it in context.

Comment: Specifically, the autocomplete does not work, the behavior that is expected is that within my modal window ... the names of the products and the actual behavior are suggested ... it does not suggest anything

I attached an image for more detail (edit question) @kettch

Comment: Ok, can you verify whether the event handler is executing?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of of my console, I hope I can help @kettch

Comment: Hmm... nothing stands out. Maybe put a debugger statement as the first line of the event handler and see if it gets hit?